# Is it possible to set up time limits for users I've shared files with on Google Drive to not have access during certain times?

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to set up time limits for users I've shared files with to not have access?  I only want them to have access during business hours.

Answer (score 0):

Well once you share it with them, they have access to it all the time. Google drive doesn't have this ability to control their time of access. However, you can control if they can invite or share the file with more ppl or you can let them just see it without the ability to modify the contents.